# Supabase - post user sign up verification step - can Supabase handle this logic?

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

I am experimenting with Supabase as a replacement for Firebase.

When it comes to the Authentication functions,  I am trying to replicate what is offered in Firebase.

With Firebase, if you create a new email/password user, then Firebase will send out a 'verify user' email to that user, and within the email there is a link back to the Firebase service that when clicked will action the verify user use case.

I can't find the equivalent verify user feature in Supabase.  The Supabase admin console has a facility to define a URL, but I can't find anyway for Supabase to handle this use case.   I'm inferring that with Supabase I will need to create a URL somewhere that when called will action the 'verify user' use case.  That seems like a serious gap to me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Supabase, on the Authentication settings for your project under Email Templates you can customize the template and under URL Configuration you can set the redirect pages for the account confirmations. Note that the url for the confirmation of the user (at least for the free tier I've used, here's an example from the docs: `https://project-ref.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token={{ .TokenHash }}&type=signup&redirect_to=https://example.com/path`) is a Supabase URL, once clicked the user will be redirected to the custom set URL.

Check the [official documentation for the Email Templates](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-email-templates) for more info.

Comment: Great answer - thanks.  One further issue.   I have a Flutter project that will output both a web app and an Android app.  The 'site URL' only allows one value

Comment: OK - I've discovered that you can pass the site URL as a param int the client API calls